# Reading table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

I'm reading an HTML file with BeautifulSoup. I have a table in the HTML from which I need to read data, but the HTML contains more than one table. 
To distinguish between the tables, I need to see the number of columns on each line by counting `<td>` tags.

I count like this:

```
for i in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for x in i.findallnext('td'):
```

This returns all `<td>` tags after the `<tr>` until the end of the document. But I need to know the numbers of `<td>` tags between the start of a line (`<tr>`) and the and of that line (`</tr>`).

```html
<tr> <!-- Should return 2 columns, but will return 4 in script. -->
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, although some guesses could be made to formulate an answer. Your example shows 2 table rows, each row having exactly 2 headings. Your code will run for each of these 2 rows (outer for loop) and again for each of the 2 found table headers. If you only want the number of headers in the first row, then why not try: `tables = soup.find_all('table'); for table in tables: print(len(table.tr.find_all('th')))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `findallnext` with `find_all`.

`findallnext` gives all  tags after the  until the end of the document as you said.

`find_all` gives you the child elements.